# Pi is the circumference over the radius?

Tags: terminology

Pi is the circumference over the radius and the radius half of the circle so what is a full circle? I know it starts with "D" and I tried a 100 words but I don't know it.  Please help, I'm just a 5th grader learning about pi.

Comment: The word you want is "diameter".

Comment: Diameter? Is that what you were searching for or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

$Diameter{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$